# Number of threads for precise timed large dataset calculations?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm not very competent on the details of Java's concurrency execution with multiple threads as I don't have an extensive understanding of how microprocessors execute concurrent operations on the same thread, make use of hyper-threading, control the cache, the OS's ability to make use of threads ect...

I have done a good amount of research to inform myself but, I still don't quite understand how  to optimize my code.

Specifically I need to be able to simultaneously retrieve input from a network connection, write the data to a file, and perform complex mathematical operations (most taxing being a polynomial regression) which requires often tens of numbers in excess of 1.0e32 being processed.  And I need this to be done sometimes up to thousands of times within a matter seconds.

So what would be a good way of approaching my concurrency for these elements, assuming that the application may be run from a server or a common desktop? If the question is too vague anyone who could point me in the right direction to understanding multiprocessing in Java would be greatly appreciated also.

Comment: Can you break down components to understand it further ? Understanding nature of every component will help us more to arrive at a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multi-threading model depends on the application. Is it like the network connection keeps sending data at a very fast rate? Are your complex calculations made on each single datum that you receive over the connection? Are the calculations independent of each other or can be accumulated after individual processing? If the answer to all these questions is a yes, then a good model would be to have a Socket reader thread write data from the network into a queue, and have several threads read from this queue and compute the operation on the datum that it read. This concept is known as a thread pool.